# App can't open with React Native 0.57.7 and 64bit arm architecture. 32 bit working fine

Tags: android, react-native

**React Native app can't open with RN 0.57.7 and 64bit arm architecture.** 32 bit working fine. and also `gradlew bundleRelease` can't create bundle file.

`react-native run-android` running successfully but app can't open. here is my build gradle file:

```
splits {
     abi {
         reset()
         enable true
         universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
         include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
     }
 }
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
     variant.outputs.each { output ->
         // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
         // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
         def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a":3, "x86_64":4]
         def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
         if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
             output.versionCodeOverride =
                     versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
         }
     }
 }
```

if splits and applicationVariants i'll update only 32 bit arm architecture , my application working file.
**ie**, `include  "armeabi-v7a", "x86"` and `def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]`.

Answer (score 1):

To support 64 bit architecture, your ReactNative version should be at least 0.59.1.
Also, keep in mind that starting from August 1, 2019 Google Play will accept only 64-bit version of the application. Here is a good [article](https://medium.com/@andriidrozdov/reactnative-and-android-64-bit-new-google-play-market-rules-what-to-do-584b067d6f1a) about it. Maybe a little out of date, because newest stable version of RN is now 0.61.5, but very informative. To bundle Android app in new format (.aab, .apk is not accepted by Google Play anymore), your RN version should be greater than or equal 0.60